# Getting error while coping a file from one folder into another in python

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, copy, shutil

i am trying to copy a file from one folder into another. i am passing the file name  as an argument  which i want to copy.

```
des_folder = 'test_corpus' 
if 3 != len(sys.argv):
    print("\nUsage: %s category_name\n" % sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(1)
corpus_root = os.path.abspath('./test_data_set/' + sys.argv[1] +sys.argv[2])
filename = sys.argv[2]
test =shutil.copy(filename,des_folder)
```

in the command prompt i am giving the argument " test.py test sport 39280377.txt " but i am getting the error:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 235, in copy
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 114, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sport-39280377.txt'
```

if anyone know how to slove it please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

This might be help you
First you have to remove space in your file name
For [Errno 2] : maybe you should put the specific dictionary of your file - C:/sport39280377.txt
Thats what i know, sorry if i wrong